# How to run JavaExec with out compile

Tags: gradle

I run a gradle javaexec in build.gradle

```
task main(type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'com.gtan.Application'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

this is the output result:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:main
```

i want run this javaexec without compile tasks. like:

```
:main
```

what should i do ?

Comment: Seems like [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: @HardikModha thank you,this is my first question.sorry

Comment: The tasks before `main` are not executed in your example, because they are up-to-date. If this is not the case, it is only logical to execute them, otherwise you could not use **source** files as **class**path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up the classpath as the runtime classpath from the main sourceSet, you're telling Gradle that your task depends on the output from the main sourceSet. So, it will compile the main source set first, in order to ensure that the classpath is correctly set up for your JavaExec task.

The answer to your question depends on where the `com.gtan.Application` class is, and what classpath the application is expecting. If this class resides in the local project, under `src/main/java`, you won't be able to get rid of compilation, because Gradle must compile this class in order to execute it.

If the class lives in a JAR that your build depends on, for example:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'com.gtan:this-example-has-what-to-run:1.0.0'
}
```

Then, you can change your task definition to:

```
task main(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.gtan.Application'
    classpath = configurations.runtime
}
```

By setting the classpath to a configuration, Gradle does not need to perform any compilation, and you get:

```
$ ./gradlew main
:main
```

Comment: I started a service on the server through Gradle main, and the CPU was overused when the compileScala & compileJava was started. Is there any good advice?

Comment: You might want to try running with the [Gradle daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html).